# fwrite not creating newline despite using "\n"

Tags: php, forms, post, fwrite

I'm new to php, trying to learn about html forms but having this slight issue with newline. The below code is supposed to take in a table name through html, then write the input into a text file:

html

```
<form action="maketable.php" method="post" name="input[]">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Table Info</legend>
            Enter Table Name:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="input[]">
            <br>
            Enter Value A:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="input[]">
            <br>
            Enter Value B:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="input[]">
            <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

php

```
$file = fopen("Tables.txt", "w+");
if(isset($_POST["input"])) { 
    $input = $_POST["input"];
    $table = $input[0];
    $A = $input[1];
    $B = $input[2];

    fwrite($file, $table . "\n");
    fwrite($file, $A . "\n");
    fwrite($file, $B);
} else {
    fwrite($file, "table not set");
}
fclose($file);
```

If I put into the form "table", "A", "B". The text file shows

> tableAB

I would like to get these variables to have a newline between them, but `. "\n"`
doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you checking this? Are you reading the file with a Windows editor like notepad? Or perhaps displaying it in a web browser?

Comment: I was checking this with a notepad. Just looked at it in a browser, and your right, it works. Thanks for the quick resonse

Comment: If you want to write cross-plattform, use `PHP_EOL` instead. If you use `\n` Windows will not recognize it as a newline. A newline in Windows is  `\r\n`. Mark's comment is quite relevant here.

Comment: i would of expected that to be the other-way around, with browsers expecting html and ignoring line breaks.

Comment: same here, that's why I didn't think to look at it through the browser

Comment: The browser accepts it, if the correct MIME-Type is sent (e.g. `text/plain`).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois This is true but it depends on whether the server is on a windows machine as well. If it's on a non-windows machine then it may still use `\n`

Comment: `\r\n` is a Windows convention yes, but most apps recognise just `\n`.  Notepad is one that doesn't, Wordpad does.

Answer (score 1):

Use '\r\n' at the end (in Windows).
'\n' optimal for Linux.

```
$line_break = '\r\n';
```

And faster performance if you replace this:

```
fwrite($file, $table . "\n");
fwrite($file, $A . "\n");
fwrite($file, $B);
```

to this:

```
$line_break = '\r\n';
fwrite($file, $table . $line_break . $A . $line_break . $B . $line_break);
```

Or more faster:

```
$line_break = '\r\n';

$write_ok = file_put_contents("Tables.txt", $table . $line_break . $A . $line_break . $B . $line_break);
if ( $write_ok < 4) { // error

}
```